# Can the timeout of conjure-up/juju operations be configured?

Tags: openstack, lxd

I'm trying to install OpenStack with NovaLXD on localhost via conjure-up and it keeps timing out...  (at home for dev/learning purposes)

My hardware is ancient...  it's an old Dell poweredge 2850 (circa 2004) that I got off of ebay.  It has dual single-core Xeons with HT enabled (4 logical) with 16GB RAM and 6xU320 drives.  The PERC controller is fried but works great in raw SCSI mode (I'm set up with software raid (LVM + MD)).  It "should" be enough, even if the end result is a tad sluggish, given that conjure-up recommends 16GB and 2 cores.  Though they also recommend SSD, I don't see excessive hard drive activity during my several attempts to bring the containers up.

After using a couple of attempts to fine tune some things, I'm stuck here where I think just a 'little' more time would let this complete successfully.  2 attempts in a row resulted in the same thing where everything looks like it would have completed successfully except for this impatience from conjure-up/juju.

the tail of my conjure-up log is:

```
2018-12-10 19:09:48,717 [INFO] conjure-up/openstack-novalxd - common.py:47 - Waiting for deployment to settle.
2018-12-10 20:45:05,352 [ERROR] conjure-up/openstack-novalxd - juju.py:745 - DEBUG:root:cinder/0 workload status is maintenance since 2018-12-11 02:45:40Z
DEBUG:root:glance/0 workload status is maintenance since 2018-12-11 02:47:53Z
DEBUG:root:keystone/0 workload status is maintenance since 2018-12-11 02:56:09Z
DEBUG:root:neutron-api/0 workload status is maintenance since 2018-12-11 02:42:12Z
DEBUG:root:neutron-gateway/0 workload status is maintenance since 2018-12-11 02:42:46Z
DEBUG:root:nova-cloud-controller/0 workload status is maintenance since 2018-12-11 03:01:57Z
DEBUG:root:nova-compute/0 workload status is maintenance since 2018-12-11 02:59:49Z
DEBUG:root:openstack-dashboard/0 workload status is maintenance since 2018-12-11 03:07:32Z
DEBUG:root:rabbitmq-server/0 workload status is error since 2018-12-11 03:44:39Z
ERROR:root:rabbitmq-server/0 failed: workload status is error
2018-12-10 20:45:05,358 [DEBUG] conjure-up/openstack-novalxd - events.py:52 - Setting Error at conjureup/events.py:149
2018-12-10 20:45:05,360 [ERROR] conjure-up/openstack-novalxd - events.py:161 - Unhandled exception in <Task finished coro=<DeployController._wait_for_applications() done, defined at /snap/conjure-up/1034/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conjureup/controllers/juju/deploy/gui.py:81> exception=DeploymentFailure('Some applications failed to start successfully.',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/conjure-up/1034/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conjureup/controllers/juju/deploy/gui.py", line 82, in _wait_for_applications
await common.wait_for_applications(view.set_footer)
  File "/snap/conjure-up/1034/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conjureup/controllers/juju/deploy/common.py", line 50, in wait_for_applications
await juju.wait_for_deployment()
  File "/snap/conjure-up/1034/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conjureup/juju.py", line 747, in wait_for_deployment
"Some applications failed to start successfully.") 
conjureup.errors.DeploymentFailure: Some applications failed to start successfully.
2018-12-10 20:45:05,456 [DEBUG] conjure-up/openstack-novalxd - __init__.py:27 - Showing dialog for exception: Some applications failed to start successfully.
```

The second line showing (safe'ish guess) a timeout after one hour (plus a few seconds because the server is quite loaded) (I'm GMT-7) has been reproduced twice so far.

At that point in time the Ceph cluster is 'almost' up and other things are blocked and waiting on the other half of the services that you see in the log, that aren't quite done (they're still installing packages).  I think it would work if we could wait for longer than one hour?

(rabbitmq was up and running, but it and other services fluctuate between error and ready/waiting due to server load, but self-correct very soon - i.e. should not have tripped this error)

Is it possible to configure that timeout via command line or some other means?

The server is running Ubuntu 18.04 and LXD 3.7 from snap, btw.  LXD's default storage is set for BTRFS and the network is a native bridge (br0 - not lxd's lxdbr0)

Comment: I just had a thought...  btrfs is not block storage, so tomorrow I'm going to try a dedicated zfs pool to see if there's any extra efficiency and if it makes a difference.  I'll report back.

Comment: I may also try LXD production setup guidance...  there are tidbits in there about number of open file handles & whatnots that may quite apply while 17 containers are simultaneously installing packages

Answer (score 0):

yup switching to a ZFS pool did the trick.  It took 5.8 hours to do the deploy and another half hour for the post deploy.

One thing that I noticed different was the RAM utilization (I was watching `top` in another window).  With BTRFS it fluctuated but rarely went above 3GB, while buff/cache monopolized the rest of my ram.  With ZFS, it soon went 3-4GB+ and continued to climb while buff/cache left a good 1GB- free until the end of the deployment when services started running.

And so I'm thinking that fs caching with BTRFS put too much pressure on the memory of the system, keeping the processes from operating at peak efficiency